# こんな ambigious meaning

Tags: meaning

In this sentence, I'm not too sure what こんな means, I gather that it might be the speaker is using it in a way which is comparing the other persons voice to their own. Something along the lines of 'this voice, is mine'. I'm unsure what it is referring to specifically in this context.

> 率直な感想を述べた。こんな声なのか、俺は。

Comment: As you probably know, こんな may convey different emotions, hence countless use cases. I'll share a nice post related with こんな but note that it may not perfectly align with the use-case/context in your example : [14330 「こんな夢を見た。」- why not この?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14330/%e3%81%93%e3%82%93%e3%81%aa%e5%a4%a2%e3%82%92%e8%a6%8b%e3%81%9f-why-not-%e3%81%93%e3%81%ae) I hope it adds extra knowledge rather than confuse you :)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'll give it a look

Answer (score 1):

literally, roughly "Is this kind of voice, that I (have)"

Still thinking literally, if I had to translate it I'd say something along the lines of "this is how my voice sounds?". ie: "So this is how I sound like?" - like after hearing a recording of your own voice.

BUT, 声 can also mean opinion/point of view.
With more context, opinion or point of view might make more sense.
ie: He spoke candidly, and is now surprised to find out what he **actually** thinks.

Or maybe the author is just playing with exactly that, the polysemy of the word.

Comment: Now I've grappled with it a bit more, I think in the context it is showing how he is suprised by what was said to him, as he has lost all his memories and has basically no recollection of anything, so as for it meaning voice that makes sense. Although with 感想 meaning an impression of some sort, it can also mean opinion too. I seems that both make sense, probably to make a polysemy as you said, thus making the writing more interesting. thanks for the help